# Inline block adding bottom space

Tags: css

I have one of my `<a>` links set to `inline-block` and there is some space added to the bottom of the containing div. I am not sure how to get rid of this and was wondering if someone could help.

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/RQ69r/1/

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fix that adding the following style to the inline-block element:

```
vertical-align: middle;
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/RQ69r/4/)

Comment: Any value assigned to `vertical-align` would work in this instance.

Comment: @Vector Except `baseline`, `sub`, `supper` and most `<length>` or `<percentage>`. That means `top`, `bottom`, `text-top`, `text-bottom` and `middle`. I used `middle` because usually that's what I want when I use inline-blocks.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you change it to `display: block;` ?

Check the updated fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/RQ69r/3/

When you want more `<a>` elements next to each other *(horizontal)*, you could use `list-items` and / or `float:left;`

Comment: I could do that and it fixes the problem, but I am reworking a design I did into a WP template and there was a reason I needed `inline-block` but I didn't comment the code as to why. I _would_ like to know how to avoid this in the future, even if I can correct it now but changing it to `block`.

Comment: You could use `margin-bottom:-5px;` or the answer of @Oriol

Answer (score 0):

This is the default behavior of `inline-block` elements. Set the parent div `font-size: 0px;`

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/RQ69r/7/

```
.row_20 {
    width: 20%;
    font-size: 0px;
}
```

And set the correct font-size of the child `element`

```
.header .logo {
    font-size: 13px;  <-- set font size
    height: 45px;
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    background: blue;
}
```